# Asp.net Calendar How to

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a question about a project where I am working on 
it is a calendar where you can put a comment to a special day / year

I'm using atm the asp.net calendar control.

Here is the image of this idea:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AkSk9.jpg]

Here is the Markup code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"  MasterPageFile="~/Calender.master" CodeFile="Calender.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
<form id="Form1" runat="server">
<asp:ScriptManager ID="SM1" runat="server" />
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UP1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Calendar ID="Calendar1" ShowGridLines="true" CellPadding="15"  runat="server"
            OnDayRender="Calendar1_DayRender"  OnSelectionChanged="Calendar1_SelectionChanged  ">

            </asp:Calendar>
        <br />
        <asp:FormView ID="FormView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="true"
            DataKeyNames="date" DataSourceID="todoSrc" DefaultMode="Edit">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblTodo" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="txtTodo" Text="Afspraak:" />
                <br />
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtTodo" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Columns="30" Rows="5"
                    Text="<%# Bind('todo') %>"></asp:TextBox>
                    <br /><br />

                <asp:LinkButton ID="butUpdate" runat="server" Text="Update" CommandName="Update" />
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <InsertItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblTodo" runat="server" Text="Toevoegen:" AssociatedControlID="txtTodo" />
                <br />
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtTodo" runat="server" Text="<%# Bind('todo') %>" TextMode="MultiLine"
                    Columns="30" Rows="5" />
                <br />
                <asp:Button ID="butInsert" runat="server"  Text="Add" CommandName="Insert" />
            </InsertItemTemplate>
        </asp:FormView>
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="butAddNew" runat="server" Text="Toevoegen" OnClick="butAddNew_Click" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel> 
<SelectParameters>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="todoSrc" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Stefan %>"
    DeleteCommand="DELETE Calender WHERE date=@date" InsertCommand="INSERT Calender (date,todo) VALUES (@date,@todo)"
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM Calender WHERE date=@date" UpdateCommand="UPDATE Calender SET todo=@todo WHERE date=@date">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter Name="date" ControlID="Calendar1" PropertyName="SelectedDate" />
    </SelectParameters>
    <InsertParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter Name="date" ControlID="Calendar1" PropertyName="SelectedDate" />
    </InsertParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="calendarSrc" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Stefan %>"
    SelectCommand="SELECT date FROM Calender"></asp:SqlDataSource>
    </form>
</asp:Content>
```

And here is the Codebehind cs file

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Collections;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{


    DataView todo = new DataView();

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (Calendar1.SelectedDate == DateTime.MinValue)
            Calendar1.SelectedDate = Calendar1.TodaysDate;
    }


    void Page_PreRender()
    {
        todo = (DataView)calendarSrc.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
        todo.Sort = "date";


    }

    protected void Calendar1_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
    {
        if (todo.FindRows(e.Day.Date).Length > 0)
            e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Aqua;

    }

    protected void Calendar1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FormView1.ChangeMode(FormViewMode.Edit);

    }

    protected void butAddNew_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FormView1.ChangeMode(FormViewMode.Insert);


    }


}
```

Comment: My question is how can i do it like i decribe in the image

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the text directly in the cell of the target day?

Use the OnDayRender method that you already have to add a literal control:

```
protected void Calendar1_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
{
    if (todo.FindRows(e.Day.Date).Length > 0)
        e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Aqua;

    if (e.Day.Date.Day == 18)
        e.Cell.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br />Test to show on the calendar."));
}
```

Good luck,

Patrick